# Alternative ways of saying "Try your best"?

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, idiom-requests

I want to encourage my friend through a hardship of his career.
What are some alternative ways of saying "Try your best"?

Comment: You Do Your Worst - And We Will Do Our Best - W. Churchill

Comment: Give it the old college try!

Comment: One I've actually used:  Every job has some toilets that need to be cleaned.

Comment: There are also many variants of the adage "Don't let the goose-pluckers get your down."

Answer (score 3):

Hang in there!

Keep up the good work!

This too shall pass.

Remember, it's only a job.

Don't let them get to you.

Don't let it get you down.

Comment: +1 for "... only a job," although I'd recommend adding "f^^^ing": "Remenber, it's only a f^^^ing job."  (At the end of the day, that's all it is.)(On the other hand, if he/she can't find a *f^^^ing job, then maybe "Hang [the f^^^] in there" would be more appropriate!)

Comment: @PapaPoule adding the f-word makes every sentence a tad bit more effective! I know you'll agree with me on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not "Try your best" but "Do your best".  What did Yoda say about 'try'?

Make your mark!  Wow them with your creativity.

At the very least, strive to be your best.